# How to recognize if a Ubuntu VPS runs as a container?

Tags: container

I got plenty of VPS from two hosting providers, one of them is on KVM and I recognize that by [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/838344/346256). I have a container VPS and this procedure doesn't work.

I want to recognize how to figure out the host that I connected by SSH, is on a containerization or a virtualization environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer you linked to seems quite good. I don't understand what that answer lacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LXD Containers return an accurate response to hostnamectl.

```
$ hostnamectl status

   Static hostname: minecraft
         Icon name: computer-container
           Chassis: container   <------------------------------
        Machine ID: 968f535e727041b7b8ef53f8c1a5b4d6
           Boot ID: 5b60eb28aafe4e1cb6c70cc23b3b78df
    Virtualization: lxc  <-------------------------------------
  Operating System: Ubuntu 19.10
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-29-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```